# Month over month percentage in data query model

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I am having issues getting the month over month percentage in power bi. I have column that contains the yyyy-mm data in dim table and i have a percentage column in fact table. I dont see Time intelligence under Quick measure as well.

```
Percentage MoM% =
IF (
    ISFILTERED ( 'output'[Period] ),
    ERROR ( "Time intelligence quick measures can only be grouped or
             filtered by the Power BI-provided date hierarchy or primary date column." ),
    VAR __PREV_MONTH =
    CALCULATE ( [Percentage], DATEADD ( 'output'[Period].[Date], -1, MONTH ) )
        RETURN
            DIVIDE ( [Percentage] - __PREV_MONTH, __PREV_MONTH )
    )
```

Getting error that time intelligence needs date hierarchy but i dont have one. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: You need a date table or to turn on auto time intelligence https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/automatic-time-intelligence-in-power-bi/

Comment: Auto date/time is already enabled but still getting same issues

Comment: Can anyone help with the same?